# Can Azure Backup and ASR protect the same workload?

Tags: backup, azure, disaster-recovery

I plan to use [both Azure Site Recovery for high availability & DR of on-prem workloads replicated on Azure & Azure Backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup#how-does-azure-backup-differ-from-azure-site-recovery) for safety & recoverability of data related to the same set of workloads. I came across this statement online (from September 2015) on the Azure Feedback forum, that puzzled me - 
"[Azure Backup and ASR can't protect the same workload](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/256299-site-recovery/suggestions/9978900-support-long-term-retention-or-backup-integration)"

Is it true that I can only implement Azure Site Recovery or Azure Backup on the same workload?

Comment: Interesting question, I'd ask the Azure support team directly instead of here. better to know what kind of backup they support and what not before deploying and configuring anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed both Azure Backup and Azure Site Recovery on the same on-premise server and then worked with both through the Azure portal, so it does work. Having said that it was in a classroom to do demonstrations on. I wold follow Noor Khaldi's advice and contact Azures support to make sure that they will support a production system running both products.